# How to check previous line in sed script?

Tags: bash, sed

I need to suppress a lot of MSVC warnings in some C++ code.

Before:

```
//...
#include <atomic>
//...
```

After:

```
//...
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : 4995)
#include <atomic>
#pragma warning(pop)
//...
```

I'm trying to use sed for this purpose:

```
sed -b -r -i "s;(\s*#include <atomic>.*);#pragma warning(push)\n#pragma warning(disable : 4995)\n\1\n#pragma warning(pop);" macarena.h
```

Just replaces 1 line with 3. But I want to run this script multiple times. How to check if previous line matches `#pragma warning(disable : 4995)`, and ignore current line if it so?

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -0777 -pe '$disable = "#pragma warning(disable : 4995)\n";
                $push    = "#pragma warning(push)\n";
                $pop     = "#pragma warning(pop)";
                s/(?<!\Q$disable\E)(#include <atomic>)/$push$disable$1\n$pop/g
               ' -- file
```

- `-0777` sets the "slurp mode", i.e. it reads the whole file into memory and processes it
- `-p` prints each block after processing
- `(?<!...)` is a negative look behind assertion, it means "not preceded by", i.e. the substitution replaces the include only if it's not preceded by the disable pragma.

I find it more readable than the sed solution

```
sed $'/^#pragma warning(disable : 4995)/{n;n}
      /^#include <atomic>/{i#pragma warning(push)\\\n#pragma warning(disable : 4995)\n;
                           a#pragma warning(pop)\n}' file
```

which skips checking the following line when it meets the disable.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -v p='#pragma warning(disable : 4995)' '
index($0, "#include <atomic>") && prev != p {
      $0 = sprintf("#pragma warning(push)\n%s\n%s\n#pragma warning(pop)", p, $0)
}
{ prev=$0 } 1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the line `#include <atomic>` is placed between `pragma warning(disable : 4995)` and `pragma warning(pop)` we can just exclude such [ranges](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-29)

```
sed -b -r -i '/#pragma warning\(disable : 4995\)/,/#pragma warning\(pop\)/ !{
    s;(\s*#include <atomic>.*);#pragma warning(push)\n#pragma warning(disable : 4995)\n\1\n#pragma warning(pop);
}' macarena.h
```